# Is knowledge of right and wrong the 'first' knowledge?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, knowledge

Personally, I do not commit to memory a great many useless details but, prefer to remember how to understand, how to act and, how to answer.

For example, if fixing a computer I do not have in my mind the detail of all of the steps but instead what the procedure is and where/how to find it (with the details).

Sometimes this concerns me, that I do not remember every eloquent detail but, it occurs to me that rather than knowing every tiny unspecified detail of a matter, it is more efficient to know understanding and how to answer.

So, is knowledge of this is right and that is wrong the 'first' knowledge?

Comment: How about the knowledge of edible and inedible, predator and prey, male and female common to all animals?

Comment: @DanChristensen I suppose that equates to this plant is right, that plant is wrong, etc.

Comment: I assumed you meant right and wrong moral choices.

Comment: Interesting that you're not the first who thinks so. "Knowledge of right and wrong" could stand for "Knowledge of everything".

Comment: I would say the first knowledge would be the CONCEPT of the topic.  Concepts only exist in the mind.  They are not physical. Once you apply the concept to reality this is different from the concept by itself. Knowledge is usually the word for how to apply something be it a concept or an act. Knowing the best application of something combines the concept & physical parts . This combination is called WISDOM.  If you are only talking about physical acts then you are likely speaking about knowledge by itself & not wisdom necessarily.  Many physical acts do not require understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the tool is more important than a mastery.
The ability to grow.
Mastery cannot come without the proper tool.
Be of mind or flesh.

The first knowledge I would think we gain is the ability to ,initially, survive.

I will say that this concept is the first lesson that leads to our mindset.